# Is there a term for "You might also like"-features?

Tags: marketing, shopping-cart, shopping, opencart

Talking about plugins and features for web shops, a good idea is to have a feature saying "Based on this product, you might also like these products: *list of products*".

The "You might also like"-feature is about **statistics and correlations** telling you that "**People who buy this product also tend to buy these products**"- products that might not be related at all.

I'll be having a speech on digital marketing, for a potential customer needing assistance on web shop improvement. For that case I'm looking for a shorter term for the above mentioned kind of feature.
I believe I once heard a shorter term for it, but I forgot it :(

Comment: "_related_ products"?

Comment: No, it's not the same. Related products are based on product groups/types and accessoires that match. 
The "You might also like"-feature is about statistics and correlations telling you that "People who buy this product also tend to buy these products"- products that might not be related at all.

Comment: "_recommended_"?

Comment: The marketing terms would be upsell and cross sell widgets.

Comment: The marketing term is *cross promotion* for any offer that is for another product or *up sell* for any product that is an add-on or complimentary feature such as a memory up-grade or a car charger or a carrying case. The mechanism is simply a recommendation. What is recommended is up to you and how you set up the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe "recommended" (as in "*recommended* products") would be a suitable short term for this section/feature. The tool for creating such a feature would seem to be a "recommendation engine" (or "recommendation system").

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994642/what-do-i-need-in-a-database-for-customers-who-bought-this-item-also-bought

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term as it relates to selling products is called "Cross Selling" as opposed to the technology that allows for suggested similar results of a search which is known as "Incremental Search".

Answer (score 1):

**Upsell widget** is the term for features like "viewed together" where you encourage a customer to buy a better and more expensive product.
**Cross sell widget** is used for feauters like "ppl who bought this also bought that") where you invite a cusomer to buy related products.